# how to reslove Each Request DTO can only be handled by 1 service in service stack

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, servicestack

I have two services which wil be having both the service will be having the same DTO.

```
     [Route("service1\GetData","Get")]
     [Route("service2\GetData","Get")]
     public class GetData 
       { 
           public string MessageID {get;set;}
           public string Message {get;set;}
       }
```

Based on the service  I have to perform the different opertaion that i have resloved through the "name instance in container"

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceStack Routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing) should have `/` slashes and for consistency the HTTP Verbs should ideally be upper case, e.g:

```
[Route("/service1/GetData", "GET")]
[Route("/service2/GetData", "GET")]
public class GetData 
{ 
   public string MessageID {get;set;}
   public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

If you're saying they're different Services, then they should be different DTOs for each Service:

```
[Route("/service1/GetData", "GET")]
public class GetData1
{ 
   public string MessageID {get;set;}
   public string Message {get;set;}
}

[Route("/service2/GetData", "GET")]
public class GetData2
{ 
   public string MessageID {get;set;}
   public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

It's not clear what the motivation would be to combine multiple Services into a single Request DTO and Service implementation but please read the [importance of DTOs and DRY vs Intent](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos). DTOs define your Service contract, it's more important that they clearly capture your Service design then any C# concerns like DRY'ing declarative property definitions.

But if you really want them implemented in the same Service implementation you can inspect the `base.Request` of your Service to distinguish the route the Service was called with, e.g:

public class MyService
{
    public object Any(GetData request)
    {
        if (base.Request.PathInfo.StartsWith("/service2/GetData")
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

The `Request.GetRoute()` extension method is also available to fetch the matching Route definition the Service was called with.

Comment: nope that doesn't slow my problem. I have a adapters and handler on top of that and only settings will get change that we are sloving with help of named instance.

Comment: @chandan then you need to clearly articulate exactly what the question you want answered is, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).